# Block user input with regex

Tags: javascript, php, html

I don't want to place too many restrictions on the content of html text input, but I also don't want javascript or php or backtick shell execs in there either, so I am thinking to sanitize input that way:

```
s/<?php//g
s/<script//g
s/`//g
```

I am hoping these will cleanup 90% of the bad intents.

Data will be saved to db.

Comment: After sanitizing `<<scriptscript` there still will be `<script`, lol

Comment: What's the target of this action?

Comment: <input type='text' name="tag" id="tag" placeholder="50 characters" data-role="none" onKeyDown="return ignore_keys1 (event);" onKeyDown="limitText2(this,50);" onKeyUp="limitText2(this,50);">

Comment: Edit your question. What do you do with input text? Save to db?

Comment: text input data will be saved to db

Comment: @CindyTurlington Your replace regexps look like Perl.

Comment: why not just replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` to render it inert, rather than error prone regexes? i.e. with `str_replace()`

Comment: If you are just saving to db, then there is no sanitisation required. No DB will interpret your data, and as long as you are saving it correctly, there is never any risk of SQL injection. You should perform XSS procedures at the time the untrusted data is to be displayed again.